# Page with Repeater or AJAX call and create table on fly?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm getting into AJAX/jQuery from plain ASP.NET programming.

Right now I have web form with `Repeater` that bound on server-side and basically HTML table with data. I'm, doing sorting, coloring, etc on a client.

I also have some filtering fields (date range, etc) and "Refresh" button which does postback to refresh page.

I'm wondering if it's going to be more benefitial/lighter to fill HTML table using data from AJAX call?

So, user pressing "Refresh" and I grab JSON with new data and re-populate Table? On page start I make my default AJAX call?

This way:

1. Page will load quick
2. There will be no need to reload/post
3. User will have visual que (spinner) when data being refreshed

Am I correct in my idea on how to do this or it should be done old way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ASP.NET AJAX Update Panel for this, would take a lot of the hard work out of it for you.

I'd also recommend having a play with Knockout.js, which provides an excellent way of binding the client interface to a JSON object model.  You could then have jQuery fetch the data from the server with the client, and the knockout would handle the interface changes.

http://knockoutjs.com/

Otherwise your method would also work.

Comment: Marking as answer because knockoutjs seems exactly what I need together with my data!

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid using ASP.NET for stuff like this. Although it seems tempting now it's very easy to use ASP.NET badly which will cause headache further down the road. My suggestion is to use a simple webservice which fills a HTML table using an AJAX call. It's a lot easier to debug when things go wrong (and they will at some point) and is much more efficient than using Update Panels.

Comment: Update Panels out of question. If i do it - it will be NON-ASP.NET ajax. Will be plain jQuery to fill plain HTML table. Current version of site using repeaters and postbacks with no JS.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a jQuery table plugin, like [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/).

It's as easy as calling `$('#yourTableId').dataTable();`. This will give you a sortable, filterable, paged table... plug-and-play with your existing code and table. The sorting and filtering is built-in and requires no post-backs.

It is also compatible with [AJAX data sources](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) (JSON feed) when you are returning large data sets, but that requires a little more work.

Comment: I looked at it yesterday, we have specific UI design and it will be hard to get DataTables to work.

Comment: Interesting. It's totally customizable, but not knowing what you are doing I guess there could be issues. And yeah, knockout.js is pretty cool to use too. Good luck!

Comment: Mike, we have sorting options outside of table as radiobuttons. We have another copy of "header" that stays at top of the window when scrolling and we have all the styles already done. So, it is kind of too late and too much to add datatables.